# Computer power supply fault

Tags: power-supply, power, troubleshooting

This is my first post to the site; it's been a great resource to me in both my professional and personal lives. It's about time I registered!

So I went to boot up my desktop this morning and nothing happened. I'd been having some power issues in the past with it, mostly just at startup. I would simply have to mash the power button a few times. Immediately I start thinking that the power on signal isn't going through to the motherboard. After this morning though, I start fearing that the mobo is toast, so I decided to do a little troubleshooting to rule that out.

I pulled the PSU and got out the multimeter. I shorted the circuit between pins 15 (common) and 16 (power on) on the main motherboard cable to stimulate the power on signal (first I tested continuity and got about 2.5v flowing through). No start up. No fan and no voltages in any of the other pins. The standby voltage is at a steady 5v, which it should be.  I checked all voltages on all pins with and without shorting those pins. Nothing.

The power supply is acting how it should when it's off, but if I try to start it up inside or outside the machine, no luck. I'm thinking bad PSU and perhaps the mobo is okay (but I didn't really troubleshoot it).

I really don't want to break open the PSU and test in there; I'll just purchase a new unit and save myself the trouble of finding components. 
I just wanted to get the community's opinion in whether or not this does indeed seem like a PSU problem or if I should poke around elsewhere. If you have any tips or tricks your input would be appreciated as well. I just can't get the darn thing to turn on and distribute power!

Comment: Mmmm. Was there a question anywhere?

Comment: Swap with another pc psu. If it works, that's all you need to know to troubleshoot

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not show and tell. It's also not a kaffeeklatsch. The first paragraph is just superfluous time-wasting fluff. We don't care about your personal life, only your electronics-related question. Since your post isn't even a question, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Please don't bother commenting unless you read it in its entirety. There is indeed a question, you simple have to read. If you have no input to provide then move along. Additionally, why wouldn't I mention the steps that I've already taken to isolate the issue? That just seems irresponsible not to do so.

Comment: There are few post on this site that might help you. Read the [Troubleshooting PCB of an ATX power supply?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176058/troubleshooting-pcb-of-an-atx-power-supply/176061#176061) post. I also have include few links to other similar posts on this web site. BTW welcome to electronic stackexchange

Comment: It certainly sounds dead to me (and from your question it seems that you have the same opinion). If I were you, I'd just buy a new one. For the cost of a computer power supply, it is not worth wasting your time thinking too hard about this. (I also think your question is not a very good one, in that there is nothing particularly electronics-related here. Mostly, you seem to want someone to confirm your diagnosis. But based on the information you provide, the power supply is very obviously not working as intended, and it seems there is nothing to say that you don't already know.)